# How do I enter Segno, Coda, D.S. al Coda into TuxGuitar?

Tags: notation, repeats, tuxguitar

I've figured out TuxGuitar for the most part, and although I can do simple repeats, I can't find where "D.S. al Coda", "To Coda", and the symbol buttons are.

How do I enter Segno, Coda, D.S. al Coda into TuxGuitar?

Comment: This question seems like it would be better suited to the TuxGuitar support forum / chat / technical support.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, TuxGuitar does not currently have this capability. Posts on their [forum](http://www.tuxguitar.com.ar/forums.html) have been suggesting such an implementation for years, but it has not yet been acted upon.

If you need software that can provide such markings, I recommend free/open-source programs like [MuseScore](https://musescore.com/) or [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/) (my personal favorite). Finale, Sibelius, and Dorico also have these capabilities, but you'll need to pay for the software.